# TypeOf issue with jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with some code...

This is the code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.inc = function(url, transform, post, t) {
        return this.length && url ? this.each(function() {
            t = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(txt, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    t.html($.isFunction(transform) ? transform(txt, url) : txt);
                    $.isFunction(post) && post(url, jqXHR, textStatus);
                }
            });
        }) : this;
    };

    $(function() {
    $('[class*="inc:"]').each(function() {
        var match = /inc:(\S+)/.exec(this.className || '');
        if(typeOf(match[1]) != "undefined")
          match && $(this).inc(unescape(match[1]));
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

and on line 18 it's point to this error:

```
ReferenceError: typeOf is not defined


if(typeOf(match[1]) != "undefined")
```

What's wrong with the code?

Error pic:
[image]

This error points to:

```
TypeError: a is null

**return (a.ownerDocument || a) !== n && m(a), t(a, b)**
```

Comment: instead of `typeOf` it should be `typeof`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *operator* you are looking for is [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) *all in lowercase*. JavaScript is case sensitive.

And note that it is an operator, not a function, so you don't need the parentheses (although they don't actually hurt).

Note also that the [`.exec()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) can return `null`, so you need whether `match` is `null` *before* you try to use it as an array:

```
if (match != null && typeof match[1] != undefined)
```

Or just:

```
if (match && typeof match[1] != undefined)
```

But you shouldn't need to test if `match[1]` is `undefined`, because if `match` itself is not `null` then that means your regex matched including the substring match. So the following should be OK:

```
if (match)
  $(this).inc(unescape(match[1]));
```

Comment: Changed that and now I get: TypeError: a is null

Comment: I don't see any variables in your code called `a`. But you should test that `match` is not `null` *before* you try to use `match[1]`.

Comment: I'm still getting the error. See the screenshot attached to the question

Comment: Well that's gone well beyond what you asked about in the original question. Try using the debugger to step through the `.inc()` function to see if that's where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is not a function, it's an operator.

You should use it in this way:

```
if(typeof match[1] != "undefined")
```

It should be lowercase.

Comment: Changed that and now i get: TypeError: a is null

Comment: @estevangomez this seems to be another problem in different place, I don't see any `a` declaration

Answer (score 0):

This should be `typeof` (Small 'O')

Comment: Changed that and now I get: TypeError: a is null

Comment: @estevangomez for this TypeError: a is null, try using jQuery full instead of minified, and then let see.

Comment: OK, I run jquery as unminified and the errors says this: TypeError: a is null
 
return (a.ownerDocument || a) !== n && m(a), t(a, b)